# How do I make a batchfile replace a line in a different batchfile without knowing the full line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, hyperlink

I am trying to make a script that will replace the link in another script so that i can launch that link without having to input it each time i run the script.

I want this so that i can open a popup of a live youtube chat of a 24/7 livestream with a button on my streamdeck

I made 2 seperate scripts

1. link.cmd to replace the old link

```
@echo off
set /p link= Link to LiveChat =
>open.cmd.new (
  findstr /vxc:"start "" "link"" open.cmd
  echo start "" "%link%"
)
move /y open.cmd.new open.cmd >nul
```

2. open.cmd to launch the site

```
start "" "link"
```

This of course only worked once cause after that the findstr couldnt find "start "" "link"" cause it had been replaced with "start "" *live chat link*"

I guess i would either need some way to replace the link without knowing what the previous link was, or some way to delete the old script and print a new one with the new link i input

Comment: The simplest idea, if you don't want to change your methodology, is to actually supply a title with the `start` command, and make it unmistakeably unique. You'll have no issue isolating that line again with that string as, or as part of, the `findstr` search pattern.

Comment: Copy a pristine `open.cmd` to `template.cmd`, then `findstr…template.cmd` instead of `findstr…open.cmd`. You then don't need to create `.new.`, just create `open.cmd` directly.

Comment: not completely sure, what you're trying to do, but if I'm guessing right, try `findstr /rc:"^start \"\" \"https://.*\"$" open.cmd`. On the other hand - if `open. cmd` just has this one line - why bother with `findstr` instead of just overwriting it?

Comment: @Stephan, the OP's submitted code uses the `/V` option to redirect every line to the new file first. It then `echo`es the replacement line. This absolutely implies that it is not the only line. Of course that does imply, that the line to be replaced is always the last line. That in itself allows other options for the task.

Comment: @Compo: the content of `open.cmd` is included in the question without any hint that there are more lines. Yes, the code implies there is more, but we all have seen more than enough questions with some code "found on the internet" that seem to do the job, but was originally intended to do something different, so I asked for clarification. (And yes, I forgot the `v` option in my previous comment)

Comment: You could of course ask why one couldn't just have `echo start "" "%~1"` in `open.cmd` and then run it from `link.cmd` using ```Call "P:\athTo\open.cmd" "%link%"```.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just overriding it like this

```
@echo off
set /p link= Link to LiveChat =

echo ^@echo off > open.cmd
echo start "" "%link%" > open.cmd
```

which asks me for a link then replaces the old open.cmd with the new link

Comment: If there is, as it seems now to suggest, that there is only that inside `link.cmd`, then you only need one line. So in `link.cmd` you'd use ```@(Echo @Start "LiveChat" "%link%") 1>"open.cmd"```, or more than likely, ```@(Echo @Start "LiveChat" "%link%") 1>"%~dp0open.cmd"```. _As you should see, there is no need to escape the `@` character with a caret `^`._